# Ignoring folders in The Silver Searcher `ag`

Tags: ubuntu, unix, command-line-interface, full-text-search, ag

I have a structure like this:

```
folder_a/
├── a.txt
└── folder_b/
    └── b.txt
```

where both text files contain `1234` string. Being in `folder_a` how to use `ag` from terminal to find only `a.txt`?

I tried:

- `ag -Qu "1234" --ignore folder_b .`
- `ag -Qu "1234" --ignore-dir folder_b .`
- `ag -Qu "1234" --ignore-dir={folder_b,} .`

and always got

```
a.txt
1:1234

folder_b/b.txt
1:1234
```

How to ignore/exclude directory `folder_b` from the search?

Comment: is there documentation, via `man ag` or `info ag`? (I have no experience with `ag` and won't be able to help further). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter that's what I checked first. And added the examples showing that they don't work as expected.